# Remove replicate number from end of string

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I just need to remove all replicate numbers and letter "R" from the end of all rows in a column, `strain` and create a new column with those results in `mutant`, preferable using `dplyr` so I can pipe the results forward.

**For example**

```
print(df)

       strain measurement
1     CK522R1          75
2 CN344attBR1          50
3    GL065R13          32
4   GL078R100          27
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
       strain measurement     mutant
1     CK522R1          75      CK522
2 CN344attBR1          50  CN344attB
3    GL065R13          32      GL065
4   GL078R100          27      GL078
```

---

**Reproducible Data**

```
structure(list(strain = structure(1:4, .Label = c("CK522R1", 
"CN344attBR1", "GL065R13", "GL078R100"), class = "factor"), measurement = c(75, 
50, 32, 27)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: `sub("R\\d+$", "", d$strain)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From d.b's comment:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(mutant=sub("R\\d+$", "",strain),replicate=regmatches(strain, regexpr("R\\d+$", strain)))
```

Comment: What if I want to create a new column that contains the removed characters? For example, keep `R1` from `CK522R1`

Comment: @TheSciGuy - I've updated my answer to provide you with the additional column.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to learn regex but it's a difficult topic for me!

Comment: I come to StackOverflow all the time for it myself!